# SQL Count Continuous Repetition of String Status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns (`Time`, `ItemName`, `Status`).
The Time column is an hourly interval with format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, ItemName column consist of variety of item string and Status column will define the status of the item string. There are 3 status result which are "Active", "Inactive" and "Closed". The result mainly Active and Inactive, while Closed are manually overwrite when the status Inactive are repeated more than 30 Days. To do that, we usually will calculate manually the time accumulated for the Inactive more than 30 days.

To ease the existing process, I would like to ask on possibility to have a query where it can count whether the status of Inactive has been repeated for more than 30 days?
I currently working with count statement as below but not able to see ways through. Really appreciate if you could help me.

```
WITH STATUSCOUNT(
S_TIME, S_ITEMNAME, SSTATUS, S_COUNT#)
AS (
SELECT S_TIME, S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS, COUNT(*) over (PARTITION BY S_STATUS) AS S_COUNT#
FROM TABLE_OUTPUT)
SELECT *
FROM STATUSCOUNT
WHERE S_ITEMNAME LIKE 'GRUNT'
ORDER BY S_TIME DESC
```

[image]

Comment: please show some sample data with the corresponding result

Comment: will you have 1 single entry per item? or multiple entry with different status for different day for an item?

Comment: @mkRabbani only one status entry allowed for each item each timesteps

Comment: Why first and last rows are with equal values?

Comment: @Zhorov it depends on the threshold. the image just to show on how the table look like.I  will correct the image back

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the next approach may help:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
    S_TIME datetime,              
    S_ITEMNAME varchar(100),    
    S_STATUS varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO Data
    (S_TIME, S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS)
VALUES
    ('2019-12-01T23:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Active'),
    ('2019-12-02T00:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-02T01:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-02T02:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-02T03:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-02T04:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-02T05:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-03T02:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-04T02:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-05T02:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-06T02:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Inactive'),
    ('2019-12-04T23:00:00', 'GRUNT', 'Active')
```

Statement (for 3 days):

```
SELECT S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS, COUNT (DISTINCT CONVERT(date, S_TIME)) AS S_COUNT
FROM Data
WHERE S_STATUS = 'Inactive'
GROUP BY S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT CONVERT(date, S_TIME)) > 3
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------
S_ITEMNAME  S_STATUS    S_COUNT
-------------------------------
GRUNT       Inactive    5
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ask on possibility to have a query where it can count
>   whether the status of Inactive has been repeated for more than 30
>   days?

You could approach it as a data islands problem, merge continuous rows of same status into periods and use the period range to find out if the status(Inactive) has been set for more than one month.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemData 
(
S_TIME DATETIME,              
S_ITEMNAME VARCHAR(20),
S_STATUS VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO ItemData(S_TIME, S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS)
SELECT DATEADD(hour, (nums.n-1)*1, '20190501'), 'ItemA', 'Inactive'
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP (10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS a
    CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS b
) AS nums
ORDER BY nums.n;

UPDATE d
SET S_STATUS = 'Active'
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (20) S_STATUS
    FROM ItemData
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) AS d;


SELECT *
FROM ItemData
WHERE S_STATUS = 'Active';


--1: per row, slow
SELECT i.*, ISNULL(ctrl.IsClosed, 0) AS IsClosed
FROM ItemData AS i
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
    TOP (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ItemData AS b WHERE b.S_ITEMNAME = i.S_ITEMNAME AND b.S_TIME < DATEADD(month, -1, i.S_TIME)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 1 AS IsClosed
    FROM ItemData AS a
    WHERE a.S_ITEMNAME = i.S_ITEMNAME
      AND a.S_TIME >= DATEADD(month, -1, i.S_TIME)
      AND a.S_TIME <= i.S_TIME
    HAVING MIN(a.S_STATUS) = MAX(a.S_STATUS)
      AND MIN(a.S_STATUS) = 'Inactive'
) AS ctrl
ORDER BY i.S_ITEMNAME, i.S_TIME;


--2: per row, faster
SELECT i.*, 
CASE WHEN 
    EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ItemData AS a WHERE a.S_ITEMNAME = i.S_ITEMNAME AND a.S_TIME < DATEADD(month, -1, i.S_TIME))
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * FROM ItemData AS b 
    WHERE b.S_ITEMNAME = i.S_ITEMNAME 
      AND b.S_TIME >= DATEADD(month, -1, i.S_TIME)
      AND b.S_TIME <= i.S_TIME
      AND b.S_STATUS <> 'Inactive'
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsClosed
FROM ItemData AS i;


--1. islands of status
SELECT sd.S_ITEMNAME, sd.S_STATUS, sd.S_TIME AS StartDateTime, MIN(ed.S_TIME) AS EndDateTime,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemData AS c WHERE c.S_ITEMNAME = sd.S_ITEMNAME AND c.S_STATUS = sd.S_STATUS AND c.S_TIME >= sd.S_TIME AND c.S_TIME <= MIN(ed.S_TIME)) AS TheCounter
FROM
(
--start dates
SELECT *
FROM ItemData AS i
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ItemData AS b WHERE b.S_ITEMNAME = i.S_ITEMNAME AND b.S_STATUS = i.S_STATUS AND b.S_TIME = DATEADD(hour, -1, i.S_TIME))
) AS sd
JOIN
(
--end dates
SELECT *
FROM ItemData AS j
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ItemData AS b WHERE b.S_ITEMNAME = j.S_ITEMNAME AND b.S_STATUS = j.S_STATUS AND b.S_TIME = DATEADD(hour, 1, j.S_TIME))
) AS ed ON sd.S_ITEMNAME = ed.S_ITEMNAME AND sd.S_STATUS = ed.S_STATUS AND sd.S_TIME <= ed.S_TIME
GROUP BY sd.S_ITEMNAME, sd.S_STATUS, sd.S_TIME 
ORDER BY sd.S_ITEMNAME, sd.S_TIME;


--2:islands of status
WITH c AS
(
SELECT S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS, S_TIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY S_ITEMNAME ORDER BY S_TIME) - DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS ORDER BY S_TIME) AS GroupId
FROM ItemData
)
SELECT S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS, MIN(S_TIME) AS StartDateTime, MAX(S_TIME) AS EndDateTime, COUNT(*) AS TheCounter
FROM c
GROUP BY S_ITEMNAME, S_STATUS, GroupId
```

Answer (score -2):

In this case you can use Row_Number().

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use `row_number()` for OP's requirement ?

Comment: Row_Number() over(partition by status order by time desc) you can get numbering on behalf of status active and inactive just add where clause in derived table where status ='inactive' select top 30 in records.